# SceneKit SCNPhysicsVehicle problems

Tags: scenekit, scnnode

So. I'm attempting to create an SCNPhysicsVehicle in SceneKit. The problem I am getting is that the vehicle chassis does collide with the floor in my scene, although the wheels don't. The wheels just go straight through the floor until the chassis collides with the floor. I was wondering whether there was some thing I am forgetting? I have never seen anyone else set a collision category or category bit mask for the wheels on an SCNPhysicsVehicle. With that being said, I did even try that but no luck!

Very big thanks in advance.

```
    let carScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/Textures/rc_car.dae") //rc_car.dae
    let chassisNode = carScene!.rootNode.childNode(withName: "rccarBody", recursively: true)!
    chassisNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 10, -30)

    let body = SCNPhysicsBody.dynamic()
    body.allowsResting = false
    body.mass = 80
    body.restitution = 0.1
    body.friction = 0.5
    body.rollingFriction = 0
    chassisNode.physicsBody = body
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(chassisNode)


    let wheelnode0 = chassisNode
        .childNode(withName: "wheelLocator_FL", recursively: true)!
    let wheelnode1 = chassisNode
        .childNode(withName: "wheelLocator_FR", recursively: true)!
    let wheelnode2 = chassisNode
        .childNode(withName: "wheelLocator_RL", recursively: true)!
    let wheelnode3 = chassisNode
        .childNode(withName: "wheelLocator_RR", recursively: true)!


    let wheel0 = SCNPhysicsVehicleWheel(node: wheelnode0)
    let wheel1 = SCNPhysicsVehicleWheel(node: wheelnode1)
    let wheel2 = SCNPhysicsVehicleWheel(node: wheelnode2)
    let wheel3 = SCNPhysicsVehicleWheel(node: wheelnode3)

    vehicle = SCNPhysicsVehicle(chassisBody: chassisNode.physicsBody!,
                                wheels: [wheel0, wheel1, wheel2, wheel3])



    chassisNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = USBitMaskManager.boundary | USBitMaskManager.sphere
    chassisNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = USBitMaskManager.sphere

//        scene.physicsWorld.addBehavior(vehicle)

    return vehicle
```

Comment: Have you had a look at Apple's sample code? https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SceneKitVehicle/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Of course. My code is almost identical!

Comment: You might be the first person to use this sample in a long time. And it looks like Apple doesn't do even basic testing of each iteration of SceneKit... so it could well be broken.

Comment: were you able to figure this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .dae model, from which you load your chassis, needs to have the 4 wheels as child nodes.

Otherwise it doesn't work.

It’s also worth noting that you can’t scale wheels. Wheels default to using the node scaled at 1.0.

So the .dae model must be the correct size when scaled to 1.0.

[image]

**Update 2023/11/03**

Remove the collision bitMask on the boundary and set it to kinematic

```
// chassis - dynamic - has collisionBitMask

chassisNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = USBitMaskManager.sphere

chassisNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = USBitMaskManager.boundary | USBitMaskManager.sphere

// boundary - kinnectic - no collision bitmask

boundary.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.init(
    type: .kinematic,
    shape: SCNPhysicsShape(
        node: node,
        options: [
            SCNPhysicsShape.Option.type : SCNPhysicsShape.ShapeType.concavePolyhedron,
            SCNPhysicsShape.Option.scale : boundary.scale
        ]
    )
)


boundary.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = USBitMaskManager.boundary
```

Answer (score 0):

did you check github? There are several projects out there regarding Apples Vehicle Demo... e.g. one is here: https://github.com/ooper-shlab/SceneKitVehicle1.0-Swift